# Using double curly brace in Laravel Collective

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravelcollective

I'm trying to create form that create users like this and this form will be use for displaying data also using Form Model Binding:

```
{{ Form::open(['url' => 'admin/users/create']) }}

    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('first_name', 'First Name : ') }}
        {{ Form::text('first_name', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('last_name', 'Last Name : ') }}
        {{ Form::text('last_name', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
    </div>

{{ Form::close() }}
```

however it showing the code not the actual view, so I see in my browser this code :

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8000/admin/users/create" accept-charset="UTF-8">

    <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="X5MA46MJctYOYeMtZF1RoQKYmWDtAbsSoxwoOA8Y">

    <label for="first_name">First Name : </label> 
    <input class="form-control" name="first_name" type="text" id="first_name">

    <label for="last_name">Last Name : </label> 
    <input class="form-control" name="last_name" type="text" id="last_name">

</form>
```

but when trying to using `{!!  !!}` as the open and close brackets, the code works and showing the actual view.

I'm still dont understand why I can't use `{{ }}` as my bracket using [laravel-collective](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html) and if you see this  [**Project**](https://github.com/dwightwatson/neontsunami/blob/master/resources/views/admin/posts/_form.blade.php) it's work fine.

Also kinda afraid of XSS attack just like [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#displaying-data) said on the section **Displaying Unescaped Data**:

> Note: Be very careful when echoing content that is supplied by users
>   of your application. Always use the double curly brace syntax to
>   escape any HTML entities in the content.

any helpful explanation on this? thank you

NOTE : I'm using **Laravel Version 5.1.40 (LTS)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because {{ }} is used for escaping HTML entities to prevent XSS attacks for your input being displayed from your server/database.

so if someone had inserted a malicious code in your database then it would not be executable for a user and instead just print out on the screen. like so

```
$dbValue = "<script> Some evil code </script>";

{{ $dbValue }}
```

It'll output as this

```
<script> Some evil code </script>
```

And because Laravel Collective HTML FORM IS generating HTML for you to display then you have to use {!! !!} to prevent escaping.

```
{!! "<b>Bold Text</b>" !!}
```

then it'll output this

**Bold Text**

For generating HTML it's fine but you've to be careful about your values being sent to your server and being displayed out to a user. There you'll always have to escape your data with {{ }}

Comment: what about displaying data using Form Model Binding? I will have to use the form to display data for editing.

Comment: It'll automatically escape your model data values for your form so nothing to worry about here.

Comment: @GujaratSantana is there a reason you unaccepted the answer?

Comment: forgot to ask, why I cant use `{{ }}` instead of `{!! !!}` I see others project they can use `{{ }}`

Comment: Because laravel HTML package have to generate HTML for you to output in your view so if you'll use {{ }} then these braces will escape the generated form HTML and you'll instead see code on your page instead of form

Comment: You only have to use {!! !!} with Form helper functions not with the database returned values. these must be escaped in order to prevent your website from XSS attacks

Comment: one more thing after I will accept your answer, do you know this project it is using the same bracket to generate form : https://github.com/dwightwatson/neontsunami/blob/master/resources/views/admin/posts/_form.blade.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120289/discussion-between-gujarat-santana-and-zayn-ali).