# How to insert a line break in a markdown Notification

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm using Laravel's Notifications system to send a welcome email when users register. Everything works great, except I can't for the life of me figure out how to insert a line break in the greeting.

This is my code:

```
namespace App\Notifications\Auth;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;


class UserRegistered extends Notification
{

    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->subject('Welcome to website!')
            ->greeting('Welcome '. $notifiable->name .'!')
            ->line('## Sub heading line')
            ->line('Paragraph line')
            ->markdown('mail.welcome');
    }
}
```

I want to put a break here `->greeting('Welcome '. $notifiable->name .'!')` between the welcome and the name. Anyone know how I can do this? I've tried double space as described on markdown documentation. I've tried using `nl2br()`. I've tried \n. I've tried `<br>`. Nothing works.

Comment: Have you referred this post? <br>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26626256/how-to-insert-a-line-break-br-in-markdown

Comment: Yep. Tried that

Comment: @james.brndwgn use <br/> in your double quotes

Comment: @shashi I'm not sure what you mean by "double quotes", but I have tried using <br> like `->greeting('Welcome<br>'. $notifiable->name .'!')` and all that does is print out "Welcome<br>name"

Comment: @james.brndwgn it will work too

Comment: @shashi I just tried it again. It doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried inserting an empty line, or at least put some space characters in the empty line like this
`->line('   ')`

Answer (score 3):

You can just do following:

```php
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    $name = $notifiable->name;
    return (new MailMessage)
        ->subject('Welcome to website!')
        ->greeting(new HtmlString("Welcome<br>$name!"))
        ->markdown('mail.welcome');
}
```

This doesn't require to edit any templates.

Comment: This is better, {{ }} automatically understands that if the object passed to it is a htmlstring, it should safely escape the string within. 
Note you can also do something like `(new MailMessage)->line(new HtmlString(__('some.thing')))` so you can add markdown to you language files.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make sure to render the string as HTML in your mail view:

```
{!! $greeting !!}
```

As mentioned in the [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46657187/1815847), this makes it possible to use `<br>` inside of `->greeting()`.

Nevertheless, it's better to use [`nl2br()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php). This renders `\n` as a new line in the HTML mail as well as in the plaintext mail. (Otherwise the `<br>` is not rendered in the plaintext mail!)

Note: `nl2br()` only works with a string in double quotes, not single quotes!

Use it in your notification like this:

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    $name = $notifiable->name;
    return (new MailMessage)
        ->subject('Welcome to website!')
        ->greeting(nl2br("Welcome\n$name!"))
        ->markdown('mail.welcome');
}
```

Output as HTML:

```
<p>Welcome<br> 
Username!</p>
```

Output as plaintext:

```
Welcome
Username!
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work. Turns out is was in the markdown where the issue lay because of Laravel's escaping HTML when using `{{ }}`. You have to prevent escaping by using `{!! !!}`: [Using double curly brace in Laravel Collective](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38799056/using-double-curly-brace-in-laravel-collective)

For those interested my greeting line is now `->greeting('Welcome<br>'. $notifiable->name .'!')`

and in my markdown template it's

```
{{-- Greeting --}}
@if (! empty($greeting))
# {!! $greeting !!}
@endif
```